# MongoDB: error parsing uri: URI with srv must not include a port number

Tags: linux, mongodb, port, srv

when using this protocol:

> ```
> mongodb+srv://
> ```

I get an error if I include a port:

> ```
> MongoDB: error parsing uri: URI with srv must not include a port number
> ```

is there a reason for this (why a port is not acceptable)?

Comment: Mongodb has [two connection string formats](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/#connection-string-formats). You can use the standard version to specify a port. The `mongodb+srv` has a hostname that corresponds to a DNS SRV record so you would not want to specify a port. Can you share what you're trying to do?

Comment: I read about SRV online and there isn't anything about SRV that obviates the need to specify a port TMK...so why not just allow us to put :80 etc?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the SRV URI connection format, you can specify only one host and no port. Otherwise, the driver or mongosh raises a parse error and does not perform DNS resolution.

Read from documentation : https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/#srv-connection-format

Comment: I mean, it needs to use a port, so even though `:80` is redundant, now I have to do an if/else in my code which is dumb and unnecessary